# Beginner's question: Why can't I access an object's members when it is in a vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

This is probably a basic question.

I have a vector of a data type 'player' that I have defined myself using a struct:

```
struct player {
     string player_name;
     string label;   
     ...
     ...
}
```

I then having a function taking a vector of these player data types as a parameter and I want to access the members in the struct i.e.

```
void foo(vector<player> players) {
    cout << players.at(0).player_name;
}
```

The `at(i)` works because it is a function of vector.  However, I can't access `player_name`.  Why is this and how can I solve it?  Apologies if this is basic and boring.

Comment: You can access it. Post some compilable code that illustrates why you think you can't.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access"? Compiler error? Runtime error?

Comment: It should work. Why do you say it doesn't?

Comment: Compile-tests fine for me: http://codepad.org/cu7oNIzS  Please show a complete code sample and compiler error output

Comment: did you get and error message? are you sure did you declare player as a struct?

Comment: I am a complete FOOL.  I was relying too much on my IDE.. it didn't pick up that I COULD access player_name when in fact I could.  It worked when I compiled the code.  Sorry to waste your time guys.. I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score 2):

Following code accesses player in vector:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct player {
     string player_name;
     string label;   
};

int main() {
    vector <player> p;
    p.push_back( player() );
    p.at(0).player_name = "fred";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that foo() returns but you don't see the side-effect of the changed player_name, I guess?

It's because you've passed the vector to foo() by value rather than reference. foo() is operating on a copy of the vector rather than whatever original you passed to it, so the player_name change is lost when the function ends.

Try changing the function signature to `void foo(vector<player>& players)`.

(Note that I've added an ampersand to make the parameter a reference.)

Answer (score 0):

You should not get a compilation error since the code you posted is fine. If you are getting a runtime-error make sure you have inserted at least one object into the vector before you try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

**just speculation**

if you get a compile error:

probably you declare a class instead of a struct.

if you get a runtime error:

the vector is empty

no error but not result:

you haven't flush the stream. Add std::endl or call std::cout.flush()